# How can I embedd this in my site?

Tags: web

Right here, there is a website with a Google maps file of the international space stations current location.

http://n2yo.com/satellite/?s=25544

How can I embed this in a standard HTML page?

Answer (score 0):

Using your browser, you can right-click on the HTML element and select "Inspect Element" to see the underlying HTML and copy it into your HTML. In this case, if you include the following HTML, this should embed the map in your website.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
   var sid=25544;
   var width=400;
   var height=250;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.n2yo.com/js/widget.js?r=joo9"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the n2yo website they explain how to embed a satellite to your site:
http://www.n2yo.com/widgets/

This is the code you should embed:

```
<script src="//www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://www.n2yo.com/sat/iss.xml&amp;synd=open&amp;w=320&amp;h=200&amp;title=The+International+Space+Station+Tracker&amp;border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&amp;output=js"></script>
```

An example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3JemA/)

You can add more customizations to the map [here](http://i4gp220381rcufcplijo1qsha1ttjpmn.open.gmodules.com/ig/creator?synd=open&url=http://www.n2yo.com/sat/iss.xml)